# Issue with JBL TUNE 115BT ear phones with virtual meeting apps

Tags: windows-10

I am having an issue with my JBL TUNE 115BT ear phones with virtual meeting apps including Webex, Skype and Microsoft Teams. The earphones works well with Youtube on the computer and also calls for the mobile phone. However, when using the virtual meeting apps, the microphone is working well but the sound on the earphones (receiving) is completely distorted.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by going to Windows Sound Settings => Advanced Sound Option and clicking this big reset button.

Good luck